# Is the $L^2$ inner product really an inner product?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-sum

If $\alpha: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is an increasing function, we can define the Riemann-Stieltjes integral $$\int_a^b f d \alpha$$ Does the function $\langle f,g\rangle = \int_a^b fg d\alpha$ define an inner product on the $\mathbb{R}$-space of all Riemann-Stieltjes integrable functions on $[a,b]$ (with respect to $\alpha$)?  It seems to me that the condition $\langle f,f\rangle = 0$ implies $f= 0$ is false.  For example if we take the Riemann integral and take $f(x)$ to be $0$ everywhere except $1$ at $(b-a)/2$, then $\langle f,f\rangle = \int_a^b f(x)^2dx = 0$, but $f \neq 0$.

If it is not an inner product, can we still get something like the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, i.e. $$\Biggl[\int_a^b |fg| d \alpha\Biggr]^2 \leq \Biggl(\int_a^b |f|^2 d \alpha\Biggr) \Biggl(\int_a^b |g|^2 d \alpha\Biggr)\,?$$

Comment: One quotients the space by "null" functions and then it's an inner product.

Comment: You get an inner product on the space of equivalence classes of (square integrable) functions modulo the relation of being equal almost everywhere. But the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality holds for all positive _semidefinite_ bilinear/sesquilinear forms.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I thought something was fishy about this

Comment: Does Cauchy-Schwarz really hold for semidefinite bilinear forms?  All proofs I've seen involve dividing by $<x,x>$ for $x \neq 0$, which you may not be able to do in the semidefinite case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this has been answered in the comments but you might be interested in reading up about exactly how this is done over [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_space#The_Kolmogorov_quotient). Note that in that article they talk about functions being equal *almost everywhere* which in the view of Riemann-Stieltjes Integral is exactly the type of issue you brought up: the functions are nearly identical (in fact they are identical *almost everywhere*).

Also I'll a quick overview of the process outlined by that article:

- Define a function $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ on the set of $\alpha$ square integrable functions by
  $$
  \lVert f \rVert = \sqrt{\int \lvert f \rvert^2 \, \mathrm{d} \alpha}
  $$
- Note that the above function is in fact a seminorm, that the space is complete under it and that the seminorm abides by the parallelogram equality:
  $$
  \lVert f \rVert^2 + \lVert g \rVert^2 = \lVert f + g \rVert^2 + \lVert f - g \rVert^2
  $$
- We can now "mod" out by all $0-$functions by modding out by the kernel of $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ (i.e. create equivalence classes around functions $f$ so that $\lVert f \rVert = 0$).
- Our modded out space can be checked to be a complete normed vector space that satisfies the parallelogram equality thus we can define
  $$
  \langle f, g \rangle = \frac{\lVert f + g \rVert^2 - \lVert f - g \rVert^2}{4}
  $$
  in order to make our space a Hilbert space (and thus we have our inner product).

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to get the Schwarz inequality, I think you can look at it like this:

If both $\int |f|^2$ and $\int |g|^2$ are non-zero, the proof which involve dividing by $\langle f, f\rangle$ or $\langle g, g\rangle$ goes through.

So say we're worried about the situation where $\int |f|^2 = 0$.
Note that for every interval $I$ in the range of integration, the infimum of the values $|f|^2$ needs to be zero; otherwise $|f|$ is bounded away from zero on that interval and the integral would be nonzero.

If $g$ is bounded, then for each interval $I$ and each $\epsilon$ you can find some $x$ in the interval so that $0 \le|f(x)g(x)| < \epsilon$.

Looking at the lower Darboux sums for $|fg|$, we see that all lower sums are zero, so that the integral $\int |fg|$ is zero.

And so the Schwarz inequality holds in this case, too.